# Exclude directories from elastic beanstalk deploy

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have some directories that I would like to be in my local git repository, but NOT in the remote repository when I deploy to my beanstalk environment.

I have googled a bit, and found a few years old posts like this:

http://blog.beanstalkapp.com/post/38164899272/patterns-for-excluded-deployment-paths

that explain that there is this option somewhere, but I have looked everywhere and cannot find it. I think it must still be there and possibly it's been moved around?

If that helps (though it probably doesn't make any difference), I've got an environment based on the sample node.js application. Where is this option?

Is it possible to do it in a config file in the .ebextensions folder instead?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

With the current `eb cli v3.x` elastic beanstalk supports the `.ebignore` file. It follows the same format as a `.gitignore` file and it replaces it on deploy.

If you want to use `.ebignore` then you need to copy your `.gitignore` into the file and then add the extra exclusions to the file. If you edit your `.gitignore` file in the future you will need to replicate any changes into you `.ebignore` file.

See [elastic beanstalk docs for more details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore)

Comment: This should now be the selected answer. (From the guy who has the currently selected answer)

Comment: Yes, I've selected it now, even though I haven't had a chance to test it as I've been using a (very hacky) workaround. I should probably switch to this solution now

Comment: It's worth noting you need a trailing `/` behind the folder to exclude all of its content. E.g. `node_modules/`. Without it, it will archive and upload the entire folder.

Comment: It may not be necessary to synchronize `.gitignore` and `.ebignore` if using the EB CLI's `deploy` command: ["If git is installed, EB CLI uses the git archive command to create a .zip file from the contents of the most recent git commit command."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) The `git archive` command should respect the contents of `.gitignore`. In this scenario, maybe  `.ebignore` further filters what is deployed from the [staging directory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands)?

Comment: Indeed, .ebignore does seem to further filter what's not already in .gitignore

Comment: The being said, it seems you need to copy in the entirety of .gitignore into .ebignore for initial creation. .gitignore doesn't seem to be considered during creation, only during subsequent deploys (probably a bug). I'm basing this on the fact that my archive was >512 MB, until I added the contents of .gitignore to .ebignore, including my local media files.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. The best workaround right now is to create your own zip and tell the CLI to use it instead. You can do this by adding the following lines to .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

```
deploy:
  artifact: /path/to/file.zip
```

If you can script your zip, you could add an alias like

```
alias ebdeploy="zip {your zip stuff here}; eb deploy"
```

Comment: Even though this isn't the latest and greatest way to do it; this still works and shows an interesting option. Upvoted.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker any idea how to accomplish this now? The artifact trick definitely doesn't work here.

Comment: @EmilAhlbäck I used this trick on the Jewelbots WWW site: https://github.com/Jewelbots/www/commit/790c46681352e74cff4a545e26625cfd9ba6d920 and it worked; if you have an .ebignore file and are using the latest version of the EB CLI, you can just use the .ebignore and deploy normally.

Comment: The artifact trick tended to work randomly for me. Seemed to be an issue with the CLI client. I resorted to addinge verything but my Dockerrun.aws.json file to .ebignore... heh! Thanks for the help & follow up @GeorgeStocker

Comment: @emil even when using artifact deploys, the CLI still respects your commits. So it will only deploy a new version on a new commit unless you use the `--staged` flag. Would that explain the "randomness" you are seeing?

Comment: @NickHumrich possibly! Interesting. Thanks for that, I will look into it.