# Packages not installing though elastic beanstalk config.yml

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following lines in my config file

```
commands:
  install_packages:
    command: sudo yum -y install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
```

I have also tried it the way of

```
packages:
  yum:
    libxml2-devel: []
    other package
```

Both of which seem to fail to install the packages.

I am trying to install the pyusps python module and the installation will fail without those packages. I can SSH in and install them manually and than pyusps will install

I am not sure where I am going wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: sudo is not required inc commands as it is executed by root.  Be sure cwd and PATH are correctly specified too.

Comment: packages would be the logical way to go.  Stupid question : are you sure libxml2-devel is available in your repo ?  Are you sure YUM is the package manager for your linux distro (are you using Amazon Linux?)

Comment: I am sure libxml2-devel is available I can ssh into it and install it, also yes I am using the Amazon linux

Comment: Also, YAML is very sensitive to TABs vs SPACES (only spaces are valid).  Do you have the correct number of spaces for indentation ?

Comment: I believe I have the correct number of spaces, I modeled it after the generated file, I used the space key not tab

Comment: sorry for all my stupid questions, but I want to eliminate all classical mistakes : what is your directory layout ?  Config files must be in .ebextensions and have a .config extension.  That directory must be part of your ZIP file (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html)

Comment: Not a problem, I appreciate the help. the config file exists in the .ebextensions folder and i am using the command "eb create --single -t worker -k OIT-cleanAddressKey -i t2.medium" to create the eb

Comment: ok, so you're not packaging in ZIP.  is your .ebextensions under GIT control ? (git add / git commit).  What is the output of git status ?

Comment: No they are in my gitignore file as they are added to it by default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The config files must be part of an `.ebextensions` directory added to your project sources.

When deploying your code using the `eb create` / `eb deploy` command line, these commands are using the `git archive` command to package your code and upload it to Elastic Beanstalk for deployment (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html)

When your `.ebextensions` is not under git control (e.g. if it's included in your `.gitignore`), the directory and its config files are not packaged and sent to Elastic Beanstalk.

Be sure that you add and commit the `.ebextensions` directory before you deploy to Elastic Beanstalk.

```
git add .ebextensions/*
git commit -m "add eb config files"
```

Comment: I don't know what is an ebignore file.  Just add your .ebextensions directory to git and redeploy, it will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: .ebignore is the elasticbeanstalk equivalent of a .gitignore and replaces a .gitignore on deployment, so it's important.  See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763205/exclude-directories-from-elastic-beanstalk-deploy